# Has anyone worked out how to set up tag aliases?

Tags: support, tags

So I decided to try and either merge or set up alias for `nuget` and `nuget-feed` (not sure which is the "best", but anything is better than having both I feel) - but couldn't quite work out how to do this.

Under "tags", I am able to find these tags - but not really actually *do* anything with them. Anyone with some insight?

Comment: `nuget` and `nuget-feeds` are not necessarily synonyms in my opinion though. `nuget` could relate to packing and deploying nuget packages while `nuget-feeds` could be more specifically about installing and referring nuget packages.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to suggest a `tag-synonym. Edit the tag info and you can suggest one in the bottom right corner:

[image]

Comment: You have to have a score of 5 in that tag too to create it.